# Как заанмаршлить одно поле подтега json в поле структуры с помощью easyjson?

Tags: json, golang

заранее благодарен за ваши ответы.

Дана структура:

```golang
type S0 struct {
    ID           int       `json:"id"`
    Field0       string    `json:"field0"`
    Field1       string    `json:"field1"`
}
```

Мне с стороннего сервиса приходит json:

```js
{
    "id": 1,
    "field0": "field0",
    "field1": {
        "field1_0": "field1_0",
        "field1_1": "field1_1",
    }
}
```

Вопрос: 
Можно ли с помощью средств easyjson заанмаршлить в струтктуру S0 пришедший json таким образом, чтобы в поле структуры Field1 сразу встроился тег json field1_1?

Примечание:
На ум приходит решение создать структуру с подструктурой и заанмаршлить пришедший json, а потом заполнить поля в S0. Но мне бы хотелось проверить есть ли способы решения без создания буферной структуры.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21269578